# How to test this angular factory

Tags: angularjs, protractor, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a factory with protractor and angular.mocks

Here is the factory:

```
angular.module('googlemarker', [])
  .factory('newMarker', newMarkerFactory);

  newMarkerFactory.$inject = ['$window']; 
  function newMarkerFactory($window) {


  function newMarker(markerOpts) {
    var position;
    if (markerOpts.geo) {
      position = new $window.google.maps.LatLng(
        markerOpts.geo.lat || markerOpts.geo.latitude, 
        markerOpts.geo.lng || markerOpts.geo.longitude
      );
    }
    var markerOptions = _.assign({
      position: markerOpts.position || position,
      icon: '/static/img/markers/pointer_basic.png'
    }, markerOpts);
    $window.google.maps.Marker.call(this, markerOptions);
  }
  /* this is for proper inheritance */
  function helperConstructor() {}
  helperConstructor.prototype = $window.google.maps.Marker.prototype;
  newMarker.prototype = new helperConstructor();
  newMarker.prototype.constructor = newMarker;

  return newMarker;
}
```

and then I have this test:

```
(function() {
  fdescribe('googlemarker tests', function () {
    'use strict';

    var _google = {
        maps: {
        Marker: function (markerOpitons) {
          this.position = markerOpitons.position;
        },
        LatLng: function (lat, lng) {
          this._lat = lat;
          this._lng = lng;
        }
      }
    };

    _google.maps.LatLng.prototype.lat = function() { return this._lat; };
    _google.maps.LatLng.prototype.lng = function() { return this._lng; };

    beforeEach(module('googlemarker'));

    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
      $provide.service('$window', function() { this.google = google; });
    }));

    it("googlemarker transform geo in google.maps.LatLng", inject(function (newMarker) {
      var opts = {
        geo: {
          latitude: 2,
          longitude: 2
        }
      };
      var marker = new newMarker(opts);
      expect(marker.position.lat()).toEqual(opts.geo.latitude);
    }));
  });
})();
```

However this is not working it's saying me that's undefined on line: 
"function newMarker" saying that is undefined. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone kill me: 
I made a mistake on this line:

```
$provide.service('$window', function() { this.google = google; });
```

it should have the underscore as the variable I defined before

```
var _google = ...
```

The line should be like this one:

```
$provide.service('$window', function() { this.google = _google; });
```